# Password encryption in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have User model and use Devise gem on it. In my application i have an admin user who can register other users (for example:clients). Then these users can log in by themselves with randomly generated password. (But no one can register by themselves, only admin can register users.)

When I am creating user from other user logged in, i.e admin user creates another user , i want to generate some random password, encrypt it, and save to database.

How to encrypt passwords, so that it will work with Devise authorization. I guess I have to use the same method as Devise?

I want something like that:
EDIT:

```html
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  # set @user.password to some random encrypted password  

  @user.save
end
```

So every created user will get some random password.

The reason i am asking this, is that i think that if my encryption/decription will not match what devise uses users will not be able to log in with their passwords, since when they log in their input is encrypted via devise's encryption.

Comment: Please post your `User` model? You should be having `:database_authenticatable` as one devise modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Devise and you have `:database_authenticable` enabled, you don't need what you describe at all.

Devise encrypts automatically when it saves to the database and doesn't decrypt when it reads it back, **however** when you store it in the password field, it can be plain text, Devise will take care of it for you **only when writing** (so it will stay plain text until you `save`).

So in your controller to create new users you can just do the following:

```
def create
  # I assume your form will pass a `params[:password]` in plain text too
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  @user.password_confirmation = params[:password]
  @user.save
end
```

This should be enough for your purpose, don't need to *match devise encryption*

**Update 1:**

To generate a random password in addition, you can do something like:

```
require 'securerandom'

def create
  # I assume your form will pass a `params[:password]` in plain text too
  @password = SecureRandom.hex(16)
  @user = User.new(user_params.to_h.merge(password: @password, password_confirmation: @password))
  @user.save
  # Remember to display `@password` in some way to the user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be having `:database_authenticatable` as one of the ***devise modules*** in your `User` model.

From [**Devise**](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), it says

> Database Authenticatable: encrypts and stores a password in the
>   database to validate the authenticity of a user while signing in. The
>   authentication can be done both through POST requests or HTTP Basic
>   Authentication.